# Custom tableview cell multiple rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

[image: This is samole image]
This is my json data. Here it is Restaurant name coming one and line name coming 2 some times line name coming more then how to print the data in custom cell.please. help me

```
     "currency": "$",
    "state": "sale",
    "total": 243.1,
    "name": "a1238",
    "restaurant_name": "\"Food Court\" Biergarten",
    "date": "2016-10-16 07:52:07",
    "table_no": null,
    "so_id": 238,
    "lines": [
      {
        "line_status": "pending",
        "line_id": 2536,
        "line_price": 1,
        "line_qty": 1,
        "line_name": "Käse"
      },
      {
        "line_status": "pending",
        "line_id": 2579,
        "line_price": 7.8,
        "line_qty": 2,
        "line_name": "3 Musketiere (3x verschiedene Hefe 0,3l)"
      },
```

Comment: Could you please explain more?. Its really difficult to help you with this description.

Comment: is this problem occurs after scrolling?

Comment: this screenshot is from? i can see dual network

Comment: No, my question is how to print the data same as attached image.

Comment: screenshot is from android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126092/discussion-between-dev-tandel-and-siva-sankar).

Comment: I guess this is the problem from back end side. Not from front end. Please check your complete response which is coming from back end.

Comment: Show your code which what you tried

Comment: Abha point is correct.I agree with his comment.

Comment: same data android is coming problem only in ios . se my attached image is android image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

First get all values from your response in `NSMutableArray` what you want

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *restaurentsNamesArray;
    NSMutableArray *linesArray;
    NSMutableArray *linesCountArray;
}
```

After that in `viewDidLoad` add values to those mutable arrays which you got from your response

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        restaurentsNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        linesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        linesCountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSError *error;

  // Do the stuff for get response from url here.
  // And give that request below.

        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
                NSDictionary *main = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                NSDictionary *result = [main valueForKey:@"result"];
                NSArray *saleorders = [result valueForKey:@"saleorders"];
                for (NSDictionary *dict in saleorders){
                    [restaurentsNamesArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"restaurant_name"]];
                    [linesArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"lines"]];
                }

        NSLog(@"%@",restaurentsNamesArray);
        NSLog(@"%@",linesArray);
    }
```

Now all you want is implement table view delegate methods like below:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [restaurentsNamesArray count];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSArray *array;
    if (linesArray.count > section){
        array = [linesArray objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    return array.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    NSArray *array;
    array = [linesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"line_name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"line_id"];
    return cell;
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [restaurentsNamesArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Here I'm just populating restaurant names in `tableView` section header as `NSString`.

If you want exactly like android what you shown above you have to implement below methods instead of `-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` this method

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((headerView.frame.size.width/2)-47,-32,300,94)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    tempLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tempLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2);
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    tempLabel.text= [restaurentsNamesArray objectAtIndex:section];

    [headerView addSubview:tempLabel];

    return headerView;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return 35;
}
```

Like the same way I'm just populating lineName in `cell.textLabel`

If you want to do more , just create custom `tableViewCell` and create layout how you want.

that's it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use your restaurant array for section

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView{}
```

and your `"lines": [{}]` array for

```
numberOfRowsInSection{}
```

You may get better idea from code mentioned below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number restaurant count
return [restaurantArray count];
}
```

and for multiple rows considering you have restaurant as object:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of lines count.
return [objRestaurant.Lines count];
}
```

Comment: If he get restaurants more than one from json?

Comment: is it not what he wanted?
if there are 2 restaurant in json, and each rest have 2-2 lines each.
Then he is expecting  4 rows in tableview.
 isn't it @Siva Sankar

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an array of Restaurant type an fetch the data from json and add it into an array  just like that

```
var RestaurantArray = [Restaurant]()

for index  in 0..<JSON["data"].count
{
let address = String(JSON["data"][index]["Address"])

            let CityId = JSON["data"][index]["CityId"].int

            let Description = String(JSON["data"][index]["Description"])

            let Name = String(JSON["data"][index]["Name"])
//create an object of Restaurant type and map the data into object and then add it into array that we have created .

var RestaurantModel:Restaurant?
RestaurantModel.address = address
RestaurantModel.cityID =  cityId
RestaurantModel.Description = Description

RestaurantArray.append(RestaurantModel)

}
```

now use this array in your tableview

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return RestaurantArray.count
}
```

I hope this will  make a lot of sense to you

Cheers

Comment: i am using objective c.

Comment: try to convert it to objective c . its a simple loop and array declaration